# Custom Permission Evaluator for Expression-Based Access Control

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to Access Control using @PreAuthorize in my all controller methods.
for this I follwed this [blog post](http://www.dziurdziak.pl/2014/05/writing-custom-permission-evaluator-in.html)

I have following configuration

MethodSecurityConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        CustomPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator = new CustomPermissionEvaluator();

        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

and my Custom Permission Evaluator

```
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator{

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        // method implementation

    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Serializable arg1,
            String arg2, Object arg3) {
        // method implementation

    }

}
```

And when i tries to run this there comes ERROR in creating bean methodSecurityInterceptor

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 50 more
```

So my question is

Is it compulsory to use web based security?

Can't we use only GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration as shown [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#globalmethodsecurityconfiguration)

help Please!!

Comment: An authentication Manager is needed in a Spring Security application. How do you expect Spring Security to manage authentication and authorities (how to get usernames and passwords, ... ) ?